# meteor no react to updates from php7 on mongodb,but yes from mongodb terminal

Tags: php, angularjs, mongodb, meteor, postmessage

I am doing the following structure

Meteor 192.168.0.53:3000

Mongodb 192.168.0.53:27017

Php7 /update.php 192.168.0.51

Php7 /show-live-update.html 192.168.0.51

A) To run the following example you must have open show-live-update.html (192.168.0.51)
B) Run the update.php (192.168.0.51)

The algorithm...
1) Since php7 (192.168.0.51) a mongodb (192.168.0.53) collection is updated called friends with the file update.php - this is executed successfully

2) Meteor detects the change in the collection and sends the information to the client because there is a subscription called friends

3) The view that receives the meteor update (192.168.0.53:3000), sends the information via postMessage to the source (192.168.0.53) that was loaded from an iframe within show-live-update.html

So it should work properly in theory.
But it does not
Only the changes are reflected if I do the update from the terminal of mongodb but if I do from php7 meteor does not detect the change is there a way to tell meteor to do an update of some status or something to inform meteor?

The strange thing is that if I do an insert, update from the mongodb terminal if it works, but if I do with the php script it does not work.

Comment: Have you validated in your collection that update.php actually changes your collection?  Also, can you post your publication code.

Comment: Yes the update.php is fine and it executed and apply changes on mongodb collection

Answer (score 0):

I already managed to solve the problem.
It was necessary to add an observationChanges to the publication, only had applied it in added also had to apply it in update